# Подсчитать количество слов в строке. Под словом имеется ввиду текст (без спецсимволов и цифр) разделенный пробелом

Tags: java, строки

```
String str = "The party has been divided abs14 on! the issue, with moderates5789 concerned about the effects on the most vulnerable.";

String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Разбиваю строку на массив слов по пробелу. И потом надо как-то задать условие, что если в слове не содержатся спецсимволы и цифры, то его плюсую в переменную `count`. Подскажите, как правильно это сделать, без использования regex. Надо создавать ещё массив `char`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если без использования регулярных выражений, то можно просто в лоб:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "The party has been divided abs14 on! the issue, with moderates5789 concerned about the effects on the most vulnerable.";
        String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
        int count = 0;

        for (String word : words) {
            if (isValidWord(word)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Count: " + count);
    }

    private static boolean isValidWord(String word) {
        char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
        for (char c : chars) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPD**:

Ручная проверка на принадлежность символа латинице:

```
private static boolean isLatinChar(char c) {
    return (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122);
}
```

где:

- `65` – код символа `A`;
- `90` – код символа `Z`;
- `97` – код символа `a`;
- `122` – код символа `z`.

При сравнении происходит неявное преобразование из `char` в `int`.

Comment: А можно ли решить эту задачу без использования в условии (!Character.isAlphabetic(c)) ? Верней, заменить его на что-то более понятное для начинающего изучать язык программирования. Я понимаю, что у каждого символа есть свой код по таблице ascii. Как написать условие в этом случае ? Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: @YuriiS, Добавил.

Comment: @YuriiS только не ASCII (это прошлый век), а Unicode и у символа может быть больше одно кода.

Answer (score 2):

Вот вариант сделать все в одну строчку

```
String str = "The party has been divided abs14 on! the issue, with moderates5789 concerned about the effects on the most vulnerable.";

long count = Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(str)
                 .map(w -> w.chars().allMatch(Character::isAlphabetic))
                 .filter(c -> c)
                 .count();

System.out.println("Count: " + count);
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, но мы не проходили ещё Pattern. Для меня это пока не понятно )))

Comment: я думаю и стримы вы тоже еще не проходили, но может кому-то другому поможет.