# Посчитать количество слов в тексте

Tags: java

Добрый день уважаемые коллеги! Прошу помочь с логикой не могу догнать как посчитать слова в тексте.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Albert is a bad coder,";
        char[] textToChar = text.toCharArray();
        int count = 0;

        for (char word : textToChar) {
            if (!isLatinChar(word))
                count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Count: " + count);
}
    private static boolean isLatinChar(char c) {
        return (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122);
    }
```

хочу сделать так что бы поиск был char to char если буква то продолжаю поиск нахожу символ то counter++ дальше скипаю до след буквы. в итоге получить количество слов =)
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `text.split(" ").length` Это весь код

Comment: а если будет несколько пробелов... то уже не правильно считает.  из за этого хочу циклом и скипать символы до следующей буквы

Comment: Можно удалить повторяющиеся пробелы `str.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").split(" ").length;`

Comment: + учесть "тире". В этом случае между словами пробел, потом дефис и еще один пробел. Это нужно отдельно обработать. Кроме того, дефис тоже отдельно обработать придется. Так как без отдельной обработки дефиса, 2 слова засчитаются за одно. (Я уже попадался на этом в подобной задаче)

Comment: Ну тогда можно просто поменять регулярное выражение и вырезать вообще все кроме букв, в любом случае это будет гораздо лучше чем делать цикл

Comment: @DanilApsadikov если вырезать все кроме букв и пробелов, то опять же остается проблема с дефисом и пробелом. Слова через дефис слепятся между собой и будет 1 слово вместо двух. А с "тире" - будут два пробела и возникнут проблемы со split()

Comment: Слово, которое пишется через дефис это одно слово, а не два. Если убрать тире, то будет два пробела, которые будут убраны регулярным выражением

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подсчитать количество слов в строке. Под словом имеется ввиду текст (без спецсимволов и цифр) разделенный пробелом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694033)

Comment: RegExp - Regular  Expression - определит Вам любые слова . Stream API  найдет любые  слова.

Comment: Спасибо Вам всем за помощь и за объяснения! Благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задача состоит именно в том, чтобы подсчитать количество слов при помощи цикла, то следует завести булевый флажок для обнаружения начала слова, чтобы увеличивать счетчик слов только когда данный флажок установлен, игнорируя последующие буквы.  При обнаружении первого буквенного символа флажок сбрасывается, а при обнаружении первого небуквенного символа - устанавливается заново:

```java
String text = "Albert is a bad coder,";
char[] textToChar = text.toCharArray();
int count = 0;
boolean wordBegin = true;
        
for (char word : textToChar) {
    if (isLatinChar(word)) {
        if (wordBegin) {
            wordBegin = false;
            count++;
        }
    } else {
        wordBegin = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("Word count: " + count);  // -> Word count: 5
```

---

Более лаконичный способ решения той же задачи, указанный в комментариях Данилом Апсадиковым -- использовать метод `String::split`, принимающий *регулярное выражение*, чтобы разбить входную строку на массив слов и взять его длину.

```java
int count = text.split("[^A-Za-z]+").length;
```

`"[^A-Za-z]+"` - разделителем будет 1 и более (`+`) небуквенных символов (учитываются только латинские/английские буквы).

При необходимости, регулярку проще модифицировать, например, чтобы разрешить дефисы/апострофы в составе слова:

```java
String text = "Billy-Joe O'Neil  went to Stratford-upon-Avon";
int count = text.split("[^-'A-Za-z]+").length; // 5
```

или *любые* буквы (в т.ч. и кириллицу), дефис и апостроф:
`text.split("[^-'\\p{L}]+").length`

Answer (score 0):

В качестве одного из возможных вариантов:
Взяв за основу предположение, что новое слово начинается тогда, когда предыдущий символ не является буквой, а текущий - является, можно подсчитать количество "начал" слов.

```java
    private static final String text = "Albert is a bad coder,-$$%6";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Count: " + wordsCounter(text));
    }

    public static int wordsCounter(@NotNull String text) {
        char[] textToChar = text.toCharArray();

        return Math.toIntExact(
                IntStream.range(0, textToChar.length)
                        .filter(charIndex -> isNewWordStarted(charIndex, textToChar))
                        .count()
        );
    }

    private static boolean isNewWordStarted(int charIndex, char @NotNull [] chars) {
        char previoisChar;
        char currentChar;
        previoisChar = charIndex != 0 ? chars[charIndex - 1] : ' ';
        currentChar = chars[charIndex];

        return !isLatinChar(previoisChar) && isLatinChar(currentChar);
    }

    private static boolean isLatinChar(char c) { // это осталось без изменений
        return (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122);
    }
```